# Confusion in search algorithms in AI

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm

I'm studying Artificial Intelligence in my University..
I've to submit project..
In which I've to solve popular pancake problem, and I've to get search result using BFS,DFS,UCS,Greedy (heuristic),A*(admissible)..
One more requirement is, I've to find the **Solution** , **optimal solution** , **Is my solution is optimal or not?**..
The question is, there is some algs who don't search optimal path.. so when I use those to get result.. how can I know what was the optimal path so that I can compare my result???? 
Any suggestions??

- Solution is A Node (object of node class)
- Node class Having variables (state, cost, parentNode, Depth)

Comment: You compare it with the results of an optimal search algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for advise..

Comment: If I do that I've to compute same problem for 2 times.. right? It's not inefficient??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, not all of the algorithms that you named can find the optimal solution. For example, in the greedy search, it might be found some solution for the problem, but it might not be optimal. However, some of the algorithm will find the optimal solution such as A*. So steps like the following:

```
1. Run all algorithms and find the solution
2. Base on the result of one algorithm (like A*) specify the optimal solution
3. Then compare the result of other algorithms with the optimal solution
```

Comment: Then I've to compute same result for 2 times.. right?

Comment: First of all it is very very appreciatable.. thanks alot for taking interest and replying.. :)

Comment: @hashrajput you don't need to compute two times! just run your algorithms and compare with the optimal solution.

Comment: @hashrajput if it works for you, you can accept it as a solution ; )

Comment: Then Again it's a cycle.. how I get optimal solution??? By computing na??

Comment: First Search : DFS.. Second Search : (optimal) then compare my result to Optimal??? I've computed it two times.. no?

Comment: @hashrajput we can prove that the result of  A* (as an example) is optimal! Just to break the loop, you can just select one of them that you know the optimal.